# Outlook 2016 doesn't display the html

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email, outlook-2016

I have an email in html that should works in all platofrms, however I have an issue in Outlook 2016 that the content is not being displayed.
My email has

```
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>...content...<![endif]-->
<![if !(gte mso 9)]>...content...<![endif]>
```

The email is opened correctly using OWA, gmail, etc., but when its opened in Outlook 2016 none of the  conditions work so the email body is empty

Any advise?

Thanks,
Uri

Comment: I think we will need to see the full code to actually see whats happening where.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your If Not Outlook issue:

```
<!--[if !mso]><!-- -->...content...<![endif]>
```

Instead of targeting two different Ifs, why not make one the else?

```
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>...exception...<![endif]-->
...content...
```

You can target Outlook in a variety of ways:

- lt is less than a specific version.
- gt is greater than a specific version.
- lte is less than or equal to a specific version.
- gte is greater than or equal to a specific version.

I'm not sure Outlook supports the logic of if not.

However, if you are doing something with content that is specific to, for example, Outlook 2016, try this:

```
<!--[if (lt mso 15)|(IE)]>...exception...<![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte mso 16)|(IE)]>...Specific Outlook 2016...<![endif]-->
...content...
```

This is the Microsoft numbering scheme for Outlook:

- Outlook 2000 = 9
- Outlook 2002 = 10
- Outlook 2003 = 11
- Outlook 2007 = 12
- Outlook 2010 = 14
- Outlook 2013 = 15
- Outlook 2016 = 16

Good luck.

Comment: my issue is that from some reason the email body is empty when its being viewed using outlook 16 and it seems ok when being viewed in IE, OWA, any version of outlook (not including 16).

The content is the same content, arranged in div or table depending on the rendering engine.

What do you mean in exception?

Comment: @UriMargalit The If statement for Outlook is the exception to the normal HTML code we use for emails. You don't post your code so it's really hard to determine what you're doing to cause Outlook 2016 to not display content. However, you mention div, which isn't supported, which means you're doing something else that Outlook doesn't like, beyond the div and the If Not statement.

Comment: The issue was that Websense identifies the conditional if as a script and blocked it entirely.
Once my customer exclude my emails in Websense they see my email correctly

Answer (score 0):

Seems my email is correct.

The issue was that Websense identifies the conditional if as a script and blocked it entirely.

Once my customer exclude my emails in Websense they see my email correctly

Comment: That's a bummer! Good to know what the issue was